# Google maps event for marker addition

Tags: google-maps, angularjs, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

Hi i using AngularGM library https://github.com/dylanfprice/angular-gm for my project. It provides directives for google maps and markers . However there is no support for markerclusterer in this library. Therefore i need the map and marker instances in my code to add the support . Map instance is available through a service but markers are not .The library provides a wrapper for google map events and passes the marker instances with the callbacks. So i need to know if there is any event which is triggered when a marker is added to google maps.

Comment: depending on what exactly you wanna do AngularGM provides everything you need. You might need to describe what exactly is not working, you might just need to rethink your problem. eg: you can optimize your markers before setting them on the scope variable which is used by the gm-markers directive. but long story short some context would be nice to help you =)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
        var map;
        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 10,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng((SOME LATITUDE), (SOME LONGITUDE))
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: map.getCenter()
            });
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            infowindow.setContent('<div id="infoWindow"><b>INFO TEXT</b> <br /> MORE INFO TEXT</div>');
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

why not using markerClusterer [plug-in](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js) and instantiate a markerClusterer object with map and markers as its parameters? Looks like this is the most easiest way of clustering markers. But since you have labeled angular in you question, i assume you are using angular in your project; so i am not sure if you can use the jQuery's way of referencing markerClusterer. But i'm sure you can use this plug-in by following Google map api